# Extremely slow updates to small Oracle table from rails app (oracle r12 and r19)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-19c, rails

I'm not sure if this is a rails issue, or a database issue, but as this seems to be a schema specific issue, I'm looking at it from the database side first.  (Other customers with the same setup on the same app/database server are not having the same problem)

I have a rails 4.2 app connecting to an Oracle database. From the application an simple update to a 39 record table via primary key can take upwards of 80 seconds:

`SQL (83098.4ms)  UPDATE "ENTITY" SET "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_1" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_2" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_3" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_4" = '' WHERE "ENTITY"."ENT_ID" = :a1  [["ent_id", 2144]]`

If I run this update from sqlplus, it runs almost instantly:

```
SQL> UPDATE "ENTITY" SET "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_1" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_2" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_3" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_4" = '' WHERE "ENTITY"."ENT_ID" = 2144;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.018
```

I'm not sure if bind variables could impact this, or if this is the same from sqlplus, but trying with bind variables also runs near instantaneously:

```
SQL> exec :id := 2144;

SQL> UPDATE "ENTITY" SET "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_1" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_2" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_3" = NULL, "ENTITY"."ADDRESS_4" = '' WHERE "ENTITY"."ENT_ID" = :id;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.012
```

There is an primary key + index on this table, that is valid and rebuilds also near instantly:

```
SQL> select count(*) from entity;
  COUNT(*)
        39

SQL> select constraint_type, constraint_name, status from user_constraints where table_name = 'ENTITY';

CONSTRAINT_TYPE   CONSTRAINT_NAME    STATUS
P                 ENT_PK             ENABLED

SQL> select index_name, index_type, status from user_indexes where table_name = 'ENTITY';
INDEX_NAME   INDEX_TYPE   STATUS
ENT_PK       NORMAL       VALID


SQL> alter index ent_pk rebuild;

Index ENT_PK altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.015
```

There is only one trigger on this table - an INSERT trigger, so shouldn't be involved in an update (I don't think), but disabling it has no impact either way.

The explain plan for the update seems pretty straight forward - just update via index rowid:

```
| Id  | Operation                    | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |        |     1 |   233 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | ENTITY |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ENTITY |     1 |   233 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | ENT_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The issue persists if I export the schema and import it into a different schema, and even into a different database - even going from an Oracle 12 database to an Oracle 19 database.

As mentioned at the start, I'm at a loss as to how the same application server and database run this update fine on most schemas (which are perforce identical in structure), but this one particular schema runs this one update very very slowly - but only when run via OCI and not when run from SQL.

Is there any way to get more information from Oracle as to what it's doing during this update?

Comment: Activate tracing to see what's happening on the DB side.

Comment: Are you licensed for the [Diagnostics pack](https://www.oracle.com/a/otn/docs/enterprise-manager/ds_em13c_diagnostics_pack_datasheet.pdf)? If so you could check waits in ASH and AWR. If not you check the waits in v$session, v$session_wait and v$session_longops etc.

Comment: This is now resolved - application level tracing showed an abnormal amount of time stuck in commit, database tracing showed that there were 12 materialized views with refresh on commit that were being regenerated on every change to this table. This is still a long time as the MV's are also small and timing individual rebuilds only took a second per MV. Deleting the MV's reduced the commit time to zero, recreating them from scratch - and the commit time is now around 4 seconds. I'm not sure what deleting and recreating and them did internally, but 4 seconds is plenty fast enough for me. thanks!